King crown bearer -- Peter Sellers movie?
There's a scene from a movie I saw many years ago that has stuck with me, but I don't know what the movie is.
Scene setting: Dungeon or other locked area (treasury maybe?) in a castle. A man and maybe accomplices want to gain entry. There's a guard inside, and people on each side of the door can talk to but not see each other.
It seems like it would have been a Peter Sellers movie, but I've looked through his credits and nothing seems to match.
Dialog goes something like:

Guy: open this door!
Guard: Who is it?
Guy: It is the king crown bearer
Guard: Who is that?
Guy: That is me
Guard: And who are you?
Guy: I am the king crown bearer
[...this goes on for a while...]
Guard: If I open this door, whose visage will I see?
Guy: You will see my visage
Guard: And whose visage is that?
Guy: The visage of the king crown bearer
[...etc...]

Any ideas?

Sounds a bit like Monty Python. Any other little details you could add would help of course. Are you certain of the dialogue.

I'm certain it's not Monty Python, only because I'm familiar enough with their work that I would have run across it at some point. It could be one of the Pythons in another project though-- I'll see what I can find. Sadly I'm not 100% certain of the dialog but it's the best I can do at this many years later.

How confident are you that it is Peter Sellers?

Not very confident-- as I mentioned I've been through his credits and found nothing that seems to match. I remember it as something that seems his style, but it doesn't seem to have actually been him.

Looking again, I kind of wonder if it was Prisoner of Zenda. That's more recent than I expected, but it's at least plausible. It doesn't look like that's available digitally though, so I don't know if I'll be able to watch it.

There's a similar conversation with guards in Monty Python and the Holy Grail ("Not to leave the room even if you come and get him"), but there's no "king crown bearer" and you would know the Monty Python movie.

@HewWolff I know the scene-- I can pretty much recite that movie from memory by now!

The only Peter Sellars film that springs to mind is The Mouse that Roared from 1959.
I suggest this one as it deals with a small and somewhat backward monarchy (complete with castles and dungeons) and similar dialogue, ie:
**Solider #1: Hey, you see that big building?*
Solider #2: Well?
*Solider #1: Well, I saw it first, it's mine.** 
It's been a while since I saw it, but Sellars plays three parts (much the same as Dr. Strangelove) - hopefully this might jog your memory.


Yes, I wondered whether it was this too, but have not seen it for a long time.  Its the only Sellers movie that seems to fit.
